# Can I set a Firebase userProperty from background in iOS when entering/exiting a geofence?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, locationmanager

On iOS I'm trying to set a userProperty in Firebase when a user enters or exits a set geofence. I do this to have the option to send all users inside the geofence a push notification.
But it seems that the userProperty is not being set in background.

In the Firebase debugview I see the userProperty being set, but only when I reopen the app. Which is not what I want because the user might not open the app after leaving or entering the geofence.

So I would like to know if it is possible to set a userProperty in the background. And if it is, what am I doing wrong here?

I couldn't find a direct answer to this question unfortunately.

My implementation is real simple:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    [FIRAnalytics setUserPropertyString:@"true" forName:@"geofence_inside"];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    [FIRAnalytics setUserPropertyString:@"false" forName:@"geofence_inside"];
}
```

Comment: On mobile lots of functionality is shut down by default because one of the main concerns is battery life (especially with location because of some shady data collection practices).

I think instead of searching for answers about setting user properties, you'll want to search for getting location updates in background mode.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620568-allowsbackgroundlocationupdates

Comment: @windowsill uhh.. I'm getting this location updates in the background. I can see that the region is entered or exited while the app is in background. The problem is that I need to know that in Firebase. So I think I do need answers about setting user properties.